# Extract a numeral with a specific number of digits from a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Question relates to Excel (Office365):

I am seeking a solution that will extract a number with a length of 4 digits from a string.

A couple of examples of the type of strings I am referring to are:

"16016KT **9999** SCT030"

"PROB30 **0500** FG BKN001"

"MOD TURB BLW 5000FT TILL302300"

"INTER **6000** SHRA SCT015"

In each of the above strings there are a combination of letters and numbers of varying lengths and no set pattern.
The sequence of characters that I am interested in are the 4 digit numbers (in **BOLD**). Not, the 5000 in 5000ft.

The sequence of 4 digits is unique to all the strings I will be evaluating.

Thanks!

Comment: Any efforts done from your end so far? Please include in the question. Also, are all these numbers found at the same word-index, being the 2nd word in a string?

Comment: @JvdV You can't generally solve this without regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how come? (Btw, didn't know about that add-in, but that's basically macros. I'd rather make my own UDF)

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0][string-length()=4]"),"0000"),"Non found")
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your assistance.....your solution is still above my paygrade but it works.

Answer (score 2):

On more recent versions of Excel, you may try:

```
=RegexpFind(A1, "\b[0-9]{4}\b", 0)
```

[See here](https://www.domwoodman.com/posts/how-to-get-excel-in-regex/) for how to activate regex support in Excel.

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation of the content of your link? Link-rot and so forth...

Comment: Tim, this was my original approach using wildcards etc. However, I didn't know how to generate this type of code within Excel (excluding thru VBA). I will follow up on the add-in....could come in handy further down the track. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

another solution:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(UNIQUE(SEQUENCE(9999)/(FIND(" " & TEXT(SEQUENCE(9999),"0000") &" ",A2)>0),,1),"0000"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thks Dang. As per the above respondents, another variant on a solution which I will now try to deconstruct to figure out the mechanics for any future uses.  Many thx.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(0+MID(A1,SEARCH(" ???? ",A1)+1,4),"0000"),"not found")
```

[image]

Comment: As with JvdV's solution....yours similarly works. I will have to take a few minutes to work out the formula structure. But hey, it works. Many thx.

Comment: question mark (?) represent a single character not only digit number.